# Creating a macos windowless menu bar application with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swiftui, macos-big-sur

I am looking for a solution to create a macos windowless menu bar application with SwiftUI.

I have implement the function ralated to the menu bar, the problem is removing the main window and remove the application from the dock.

I have tried to set `Application is agent (UIElement)` to `YES` in `Info.plist` but it only hide the application from the dock while the window is still there.

And I have tried to modify @main but it doesn't work too.

Is there any way to achieve that? Thank you so much!

My code:

- `App.swift`

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct DiskHealthApp: App {
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var statusItem: NSStatusItem?
    var popOver = NSPopover()
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        let menuView = ContentView()
        
        popOver.behavior = .transient
        popOver.animates = true
        
        popOver.contentViewController = NSViewController()
        popOver.contentViewController?.view = NSHostingView(rootView: menuView)
        
        statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
        
        if let menuButton = statusItem?.button {
            menuButton.image = NSImage(systemSymbolName: "externaldrive", accessibilityDescription: nil)
            menuButton.action = #selector(menuButtonToggle)
        }
    }
    
    @objc func menuButtonToggle() {
        if let menuButton = statusItem?.button {
            self.popOver.show(relativeTo: menuButton.bounds, of: menuButton, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.minY)
        }
    }
}
```

- `ContentView.swift`

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Setting just the `Application is agent (UIElement)` to `YES` will not be sufficient. You will also have to change your `AppDelegate` by adding the following,

1. A `NSPopover`
2. Add a `NSStatusItem`

into your `AppDelegate` for things to work

## How to make an NSPopover?

1. Go to your app delegate. ( If you don't have an `AppDelegate`. Create an `AppDelegate` class and delegate it into the starting point of your app which will be annotated with `@main`. Add your `AppDelegate` as follows )

```
@main
struct SomeApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate
}
```

2. After doing so, you can begin making your Menubar app, by changing your `Appdelegate` to represent the following

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    // popover
    var popover: NSPopover!
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Create the SwiftUI view (i.e. the content).
        let contentView = ContentView()

        // Create the popover and sets ContentView as the rootView
        let popover = NSPopover()
        popover.contentSize = NSSize(width: 400, height: 500)
        popover.behavior = .transient
        popover.contentViewController = NSHostingController(rootView: contentView)
        self.popover = popover
        
        // Create the status bar item
        self.statusBarItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: CGFloat(NSStatusItem.variableLength))
        
        if let button = self.statusBarItem.button {
            button.image = NSImage(named: "Icon")
            button.action = #selector(togglePopover(_:))
        }
    }
    
    // Toggles popover
    @objc func togglePopover(_ sender: AnyObject?) {
        if let button = self.statusBarItem.button {
            if self.popover.isShown {
                self.popover.performClose(sender)
            } else {
                self.popover.show(relativeTo: button.bounds, of: button, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.minY)
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

3. After doing so you should/can set `Application is agent(UIElement)` to `YES`

#### Final Step

This section will be broken down into 2 sections, namely `4.1` and `4.2`

- `4.1` is for those who used `AppDelegate` life cycle to initialize their project
- `4.2` is for those who created a project using `SwiftUI` life cycle.

###### 4.1 - AppDelegate Life cycle

Go to your `Main.storyboard` and to delete the `Window Controller scene` **If you have the `Main.storyboard`**. This should get rid of the `NSWindow` that pops up.

[image]
([image credit](https://www.raywenderlich.com/450-menus-and-popovers-in-menu-bar-apps-for-macos))

###### 4.2 - SwiftUI Life cycle

Here, since you don't have a `Storyboard` file to delete scenes, at this point your app will launch with `NSWindow` and `NSPopover`. To remove the `NSWindow` that opens, go to your app starting point which is annotated as `@main`, and make the following changes to the code

```
@main
struct SomeApp: App {
    // Linking a created AppDelegate
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate
    var body: some Scene {
        // IMPORTANT
        Settings {
            AnyView()
        }
    }
}
```

For more info, refer [this](https://medium.com/@acwrightdesign/creating-a-macos-menu-bar-application-using-swiftui-54572a5d5f87) article

Comment: I have created the popover and it works well, but the main window is still displayed.

Comment: Sorry, i had forgotten 2 steps. The answer has been edited. Check points 3 and 4

Comment: I use SwiftUI so I don't have `Main.storyboard` :(

Comment: Oh. Do you have a variable named `window: NSWindow`? Could you edit your question and include the source code so I can pinpoint what is wrong?

Comment: OK I have updated that, thank you so much!

Comment: Found a fix, check the second section of my code

Comment: How? your code didn't change and it says "edited 1 hour ago"

Comment: Appologies, check section 4.2 now, i've updated it

Comment: @IvanEFan did you managed to make a menu bar with swiftUI so?

Comment: Instead of `AnyView` in the `Settings`, we can add an `EmptyView().frame(width:.zero)` because `AnyView` probably doesn't have any initializers with no parameters anymore

Comment: Inside `Settings`, you can work well with `EmptyView()` only and even with nothing such `Settings{}` .